# MySQL Error 1452 refers to table that doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to add a foreign key in MySQL using MySQL Workbench. The code it is having me use is this:

```
ALTER TABLE `movies`.`camera` 
ADD INDEX `fk_camera_movie_idx` (`movie_id` ASC);
ALTER TABLE `movies`.`camera` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_camera_movie`
  FOREIGN KEY (`movie_id`)
  REFERENCES `movies`.`movie` (`id`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

When I run the code I get this error:

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`movies`.`#sql-e20_c5`, CONSTRAINT `fk_camera_movie` FOREIGN KEY (`movie_id`) REFERENCES `movie` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

I'm confused about the part that references `movies`.`#sql-e20_c5`. This is not the name of any of my tables, and as you can see the original code makes no reference to this name.

Can anyone provide any insight? Thank you.

Comment: This is probably because your camera table has at least one record with a movie_id that doesn't correspond to any id in the movie table, thus the constraint cannot be created.

Comment: It is most likely a reference to the name of the FK constraint that was automatically assigned when you created the constraint.

Comment: Gildas, I just checked and it turns out there are some records like this. There shouldn't have been, so now I will have to look into that. Thank you.